# Firebase Recycler View Adapter (Retrieving from firebase)

Tags: java, android

I cant display using a Firebase Recycler Adapter. i hope you could help me with my problem.

**MainActivity**

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
                    .setQuery(mDatabase, Blog.class)
                    .build();
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new 
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlogViewHolder holder, int 
position, @NonNull Blog model) {
    holder.post_title.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.post_desc.setText(model.getDesc());
}
@NonNull
@Override
public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
   BlogViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        return viewHolder;
}
};
    mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
   View mView;
   private TextView post_title,post_desc;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
       post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
       post_title.setText(title);
    }
    public void setDesc (String desc){
        post_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }
}
```

**Blog** is my model class and everything is initialized there. all the getters and setters including constructors.

Comment: You need to add more information on what exaclty the problem is and give us any errors in logcat

Comment: @Kwright02 error is not showing in the Logcat. i can install the app but. .on the main activity.. its not showing anything.. Firebase Recycler Adapter is changed from those of 2.x.x   .. in 3.x.x its a little different i think.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, it's been a while since i've done recycler views, shouldn't  onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder be in the  BlogViewHolder class?

Comment: @Kwright02 .. i think it should not be that way.. and i found out an error.. i think my Getters and setters are coded perfectly..  there is a small error  which my main activity cannot link to my model class.. leme recheck on those errors. in the mean time. keep me posted k.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these lines:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    BlogViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    return viewHolder;
}
```

You are returning null. It should be something like:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    return viewHolder;
}
```